# Amazon EMR NativeS3FileSystem internals query

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Does anybody have insights on the internal working of NativeS3FileSystem with different InputFormat's in Amazon EMR case  as compared to normal Hadoop HDFS i.e. input split calculation, actual data flow? What is the best practices & points to consider when using Amazon EMR with S3?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

What's important is that if you're planning to use S3N instead of HDFS, you should know that it means you will lose the benefits of **data locality**, which can have a significant impact on your jobs.

In general when using S3N you have 2 choices for your jobflows:

- Stream data from S3 as a replacement for HDFS: this is useful if you need constant access to your whole dataset, but as explained there can be some performance constraints.
- Copy your data from S3 to HDFS: if you only need access to a small sample of your data at some point in time, you should just copy to HDFS to retain the benefit of data locality.

From my experience I also noticed that for large jobs, splits calculation can become quite heavy, and I've even seen cases where the CPU was at 100% just for calculating input splits. The reason for that is that I think the Hadoop `FileSystem` layer tries to get the size of each file separately, which in case of files stored in S3N involves sending API calls for every file, so if you have a big job with many input files that's where the time can be spent.

For more information, I would advise taking a look at [the following article](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=213586) where someone asked a similar questions on the Amazon forums.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This answer a part of best practices however I am still looking for how the NativeS3FileSystem works.